# What are the requirements for a graph to be a cycle graph of a group?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

I've been reading up on [cycle graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph_%28algebra%29), and the different and unique structures that groups produce really interest me. My question is, what is the requirements for a graph to be the cycle graph of a group?

For example, the graph on the left is not the cycle graph of a group, and the graph on the right is the cycle graph of $S_3$:

```
    o       o  o  o
    |        \ | /
    e          e
   / \        / \ 
  o - o      o - o
```

By hand I know how I could tediously prove that the graph on the right isn't a cycle graph by showing that is doesn't have closure. The proof would go somehting along the lines of:

From the graph, we know that the group has four elements. We'll call them $e$ (identity), $b$ (element at the top), $a$ and $a^2$ (elements in the cycle at the bottom).

We now prove that $ab$ cannot be in the group by trying all the possibilities and come to contradictions in each case:
$$ab=e \implies b=a^2$$
$$ab=a \implies b=e$$
$$ab=a^2 \implies b=a$$
$$ab=b \implies a=e$$

and since each element is unique, none of these statements can be true.

This method works for this graph, however I run into trouble with more complicated graphs, and I am just wondering if there is an easier way of doing this or if there is a certain criteria for a graph to be a cycle graph of a group.